# Getting several apps in fullscreen in a row via Applescript

Tags: bash, macos, applescript, fullscreen, macos-catalina

So I am writing a script that would set up my working environment by opening and then getting several apps in fullscreen via a single command line. I am having trouble with the "getting the apps in fullscreen" part, and the script execution is very confusing to me.

My hardware is a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017) running on macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

Here is the part of the script that behaves erraticaly when executed:

`script1.scpt`:

```
tell application "Sublime Text"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell front window of (first process whose frontmost is true)
            set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" to true
        end tell
        key code 123 using {control down}
    end tell
end tell
```

1. When executed while the app (here, Sublime Text) **is not** in fullscreen via the command `osascript script1.scpt`, the app is activated and goes fullscreen, but `key code 123 using {control down}` does not work, without producing any error message or sound.
2. When executed while the app **is already** in fullscreen via the command `osascript script1.scpt`, the app is activated, stays in fullscreen as intended but I get this error message:

> execution error: System Events got an error: Can't get window 1 of process 1 whose frontmost = true. Invalid index. (-1719)

Also, `key code 123 using {control down}` does not work either.

3. When executed via a shell script calling `script1.scpt` while the app **is not** in fullscreen, the app behaves exactly as in case 1.
4. When executed via a shell script calling `script1.scpt` while the app **is already** in fullscreen, the app behaves exactly as it should and everything seems fine. But if I lengthen the script to get 2 apps in fullscreen in a row as in `script2.scpt` (see below), the 2nd app does stricly nothing, and I get the error message of case 2 again.

`script2.scpt`:

```
tell application "Sublime Text"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell front window of (first process whose frontmost is true)
            set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" to true
        end tell
        key code 123 using {control down}
    end tell
end tell
tell application "Skim"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell front window of (first process whose frontmost is true)
            set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" to true
        end tell
        key code 123 using {control down}
    end tell
end tell
```

I have been spending hours trying to understand what is going on without success, so any help or clue would be very welcome.

The only way I found to get things working is to separate the code in separate steps with 0.5sec pauses in-between them, like in the following shell script code block. But I would like to find a faster and "cleaner" solution to my problem.

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Sublime Text\" to activate" ;
sleep 0.5 ;
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\"" -e "tell front window of (first process whose frontmost is true)" -e "set value of attribute \"AXFullScreen\" to true" -e "end tell" -e "end tell" ;
sleep 0.5 ;
osascript -e "tell application \"Skim\" to activate" ;
sleep 0.5 ;
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\"" -e "tell front window of (first process whose frontmost is true)" -e "set value of attribute \"AXFullScreen\" to true" -e "end tell" -e "end tell" ;
sleep 0.5 ;
osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to activate" ;
sleep 0.5 ;
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\"" -e "tell front window of (first process whose frontmost is true)" -e "set value of attribute \"AXFullScreen\" to true" -e "end tell" -e "end tell" ;
sleep 0.5 ;
osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to activate" ;
sleep 0.5 ;
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\"" -e "tell front window of (first process whose frontmost is true)" -e "set value of attribute \"AXFullScreen\" to true" -e "end tell" -e "end tell"'
```

**EDIT:** For the moment being, I managed to get my script doing what I wanted it to do pretty reliably. Not completely satisfied though, because I still have to rely on fixed delays and this makes the execution a bit slow. This is what the code looks like:

in `.bash_profile`:

```
cd ~/<path>/ ;
osascript workspace_on.scpt
```

`workspace_on.scpt`:

```
tell app "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to set the value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1 to true
delay 0.6
tell app "Sublime Text" to activate
delay 0.6
tell app "System Events" to tell process "Sublime Text" to set the value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1 to true
delay 0.6
do shell script "open -a skim ~/<path>/main.pdf"
delay 1
tell app "Skim" to set interaction mode of document 1 to full screen mode
delay 0.6
do shell script "open ~/<path>"
delay 1
tell app "System Events" to tell process "Finder" to set the value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window "latex-template" to true
```

Comment: @CJK Thanks for the answer, this has been helpful even though I am still working on it. I'll post the final code when I finish, but before that I would be curious to know what you mean by "a conditional". Do you mean a conditional loop, like in the answer below by Robert Kniazidis ?

Comment: What's wrong with the solution provided by @RobertKniazidis ?

Comment: @CJK Uh, I am not saying that something is wrong with their solution ?
My question is, when you say "even better, a conditional" in your last answer, do you mean something similar to Robert's solution ?

Comment: Yes, it's what he's named `automated_Delay()`.  I'd recommend using a different condition: an application process can be frontmost without necessarily being on screen. Generally you'd put the condition on the object that is essential to your script's execution—in your case, this will be a `window` object. Test for its existence. A delay between 0.1-0.5 is appropriate. Lastly, always have an escape clause. He hasn't done this, so could loop to infinity. I tend to use time as a limiter since it's already being measured with `delay`.

Comment: What your trying to achieve appears like a simple task, but it's very delicate. It's achievable, but you're going to need patience to get it working reliably.

Comment: @CJK Thanks for the details. I have to move on so I'm sticking with fixed delays for the moment being. I might get back to it later. I have edited my post with my (temporary ?) solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just to copy-and-paste my most recent comment from above:

> **“***Like you, I've spent a bit too much time figuring out this problem. It's quite a frustrating situation because I had a few light bulb moments of inspiration that, in theory, ought to have worked, and worked well, but ultimately didn't work at all. ¯_(ツ)_/¯ But in the process, I've at least written out a naive implementation that incorporates conditional checks and operates on each app one-by-one. It's not what I had aimed for in my head, but it works. See below.***”**

```
set Apps to {"TextEdit", "ManOpen", "Usenapp", "QuickTime Player"}

tell application id "com.apple.SystemEvents"
        set dock to list 1 in the process named "Dock"
        repeat with A in the Apps
                tell my application named A to activate
                set _P to (a reference to the process named A)
                set _W to (a reference to _P's front window)
                set _B to (a reference to the value of _W's ¬
                        attribute "AXFullScreenButton")
                set _M to (a reference to (_P's menu bar 1's ¬
                        menu bar items's menu 1's menu items ¬
                        whose name = "Enter Full Screen"))
                
                tell (a reference to (the dock's ¬
                        first UI element whose ¬
                        name = A)) to if ¬
                        exists then click
                
                tell _W to repeat 60 times -- 60 x 0.5 = 30 seconds
                        delay 0.5
                        if it exists then
                                click _B
                                if (the value of attribute ¬
                                        "AXFullScreen") ¬
                                        then exit repeat
                        end if
                end repeat
        end repeat
end tell
```

<sub>**System information:**</sub>
<sup>**AppleScript version:** 2.8 **system version:** 12.6 (*"Monterey"*)</sup>